# What/who am I series by SC #5

Tags: riddle

```
I was so gifted since I was very little
But I was also full of pride and arrogance
Compassion and overconfidence were my downfall
Compassion and self regret were my redemption
```

Who/What am I?

Comment: I think it is too broad... :/

Comment: comment on accepted answer was the reason that it is not broad :) your answer was also good

Comment: Counterpoint: this character archetype is super common.

Comment: @question_asker truely...i was gonna add another answer as "Severus Snape"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I sense that you are

> Darth Vader/Anakin Skywalker

I was so gifted since I was very little

> Anakin was noted as a talented pilot, first seen through his podracing, then his participation in the Battle of Naboo, and subsequent air/space battles as an adult.  He was also gifted due to his high midichlorian count, which made him a strong user of the Force.

But I was also full of pride and arrogance

> After being taken on as padawan to Obi-Wan, he went from annoying to arrogant.  Examples of his compassion *and* arrogance include him driving at a forbidden relationship with Padme, and the emotion-filled lightsaber duels in which fought with a less than polished style.

Compassion and overconfidence were my downfall

> His emotions, especially his desire to save Padme, were among what led Anakin to the dark side of the Force.  His confidence in himself against Obi-Wan in Episode III is what destroyed his former self, leading to him becoming a fully-fledged sith as Darth Vader.

Compassion and self regret were my redemption

> After Luke and Vader fought on the Second Death Star, Palpatine attacked Luke with Force Lightning, causing Luke to call out "Father, please."  At this moment, compassion for a son he had never known blossomed and Vader attacked Palpatine to save Luke.  His love and compassion for Luke was enough to drag him out of the hate that was the dark side (this, along with the realization that Palpatine was merely using Vader at this point, to get to Luke).  Re-embracing the light side, Anakin/Vader was redeemed, albeit just before his death.

Also...

> At the time of writing, the answer is in your profile image, Sir SC.

Comment: you couldn't have given a better answer with all the explanation. I want to upvote 5 times :) gj on noticing the avatar, since my avatar was the reason I did not give any hints, and didn't reply to "it is too broad" which came from @manshu. hidden hint :)

Comment: @SirSC Nice...it totally proves the significance of the title too...star wars is a series...and the question is by 'Sir SC'...however you might had not intended that...

Comment: @SirSC Thanks so much.  I definitely didn't think it was too broad, and love the hidden hint.  This really justifies my hanging around the Science Fiction and Fantasy SE, too.

Answer (score 3):

#### This is a wrong answer(my achievement)...confirmed by OP

I think the answer is

> [Ravan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravana) (Hindu Mythology)

I was so gifted since I was very little

> Ravana mastered the Vedas, the holy books, and also the arts and ways of Kshatriyas (warriors) when he was a child.

But I was also full of pride and arrogance

> Yes, he kidnapped Sita for the pride of his family.

Compassion and overconfidence were my downfall

> He was overconfident that he would win the fight against Ram. And he was compassionate for his sister. That's why he kidnapped Sita.

Compassion and self regret were my redemption

> He did regret in the end while dying while still having compassion for his sister.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit too philosophical but :

> The human race

I was so gifted since I was very little

> Humans have been gifted by intelligence, a bigger brain, which allowed to develop languages, technologies etc...

But I was also full of pride and arrogance

> Humans always tried to rule on everything else on earth/nature

Compassion and overconfidence were my downfall

> humans are slowly destroying everything they need to keep beeing a specy, >!cause we thought ressources were infinite (overconfidence). We know that and >!regret past errors (compassion) yet do nothing.

Compassion and self regret were my redemption

> The only redemption possible is that everyone starts making sacrifices (self >!regret) to undo all the mistakes humanity made !